# How to compute a running total in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

is there a way to compute a running total with Pig?

For example, if my data is:

```
day1, 10
day2, 20
day3, 30
```

is there a way to generate

```
day1, 10
day2, 30
day3, 60
```

?

Comment: If you think it's not good to write in hive than why can't you just write a UDF, which will hold the last SUM value to add with new?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with PIG 0.12, you have the Over UDF

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html

So this

```
 A = load 'T';
 B = group A by si
 C = foreach B {
     C1 = order A by d;
     generate flatten(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.f, 'sum(float)')));
 }
 D = foreach C generate s, $9;
```

would be equivalent to this

```
select s, sum(f) over (partition by si order by d) from T;
```

I believe this is what you were looking for. In your case you just need to remote the group by, or use group ALL.

Answer (score 2):

Hive provides a very good way to do this in a single row -
Please follow below process to achieve your target output

create a **SALES** hive table which can contain your data set (day, and sale) -

```
day   sale
day1, 10
day2, 20
day3, 30
```

Now simply run below command in your hive terminal -

```
SELECT day, SUM(sale) OVER (ORDER BY DAY) FROM SALES;
```

The output will be like -

```
day1, 10
day2, 30
day3, 60
```

I hope this may help you to get your target output.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with a solution using the cross product of the data set and itself.

Sample input:

```
{"daynum": "1", "daycount": 5}
{"daynum": "2", "daycount": 10}
{"daynum": "3", "daycount": 7}
{"daynum": "4", "daycount": 8}
```

Pig script:

```
raw = LOAD 'sample.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);
dat = FOREACH raw GENERATE (int)json#'daynum' as daynum:int, (int)json#'daycount' as daycount:int;
dat2 = foreach dat generate daynum, daycount;
xp = cross dat, dat2;
xpf = filter xp by (dat::daynum >= dat2::daynum);
grp = group xpf by (dat::daynum);
out = foreach grp generate FLATTEN(group), SUM(xpf.dat2::daycount) as running_total_daycount;
dump out;
(1,5)
(2,15)
(3,22)
(4,30)
```

Comment: That's extremely inefficient though. You turned an O(n) problem into O(n^2) just so it could be done in pig. Unless you have infinite hosts, and no budget you'd be better off just streaming through the original file on the master node and writing a new file with the cumulative total, then using that as the input to pig.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an efficient way to calculate the running total with pig that takes advantage of the map reduce paradigm? No, I don't think so. Each entry relies on the entry before it, which means that there's no good way to do this in parallel.

Is it possible to do this with Pig at all? Yes, you could do a group all to put all the data into one bag, then write a UDF that does what you want. The function can implement at least the accumulator interface if not algebraic as well.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-296 looks like an old-never implemented link to someone who wrote a UDF to do just this.